# Single button multiple events depending on the other buttons background tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a button (B) whose functionality should depends on the clicking of the other buttons. Lets say I have 3 dependable buttons (b1, b2, b3), background gets changed by clicking on it. 
I used the following command for the 3 buttons to change the background colour.

```
B = Button(frame, image=logo, command=data)
b1 = Button(frame, text = "v", command=lambda:b1.config(bg="gray))
b2 = Button(frame, text = "v", command=lambda:b2.config(bg="gray))
b3 = Button(frame, text = "v", command=lambda:b3.config(bg="gray))
```

So, when I click the button the background colour changes to gray. But, I want to make only one button at one time. So, I want to change the other buttons to it foreground when I click one button. By using the background colour I want to write the button B command functionality.

I tried as follows but it did not work as I want:

```
def data():
    if b1.configure(bg="gray):
       data1()
    if b2.configure(bg="gray):
       data2()
    if b3.configure(bg="gray):
       data3()
    else:
        print('no data')

def data1():
    as per my requirement 
def data2():
    as per my requirement 
def data3():
     as per my requirement
```

But, I get no data, inspite of clicking the buttons.

Pleased to hear some suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the behaviour you're looking for you'll need to change the `command` method for each button. You can define separate handlers for each button as follows:

```
b1 = Button(frame, text = "v", command=b1_pressed)
b2 = Button(frame, text = "v", command=b2_pressed)
b3 = Button(frame, text = "v", command=b3_pressed)

def b1_pressed():
    b1.config(bg="gray")
    b2.config(bg="red")  # Or any other color.
    b3.config(bg="red")

def b2_pressed():
    b1.config(bg="red")
    b2.config(bg="gray")
    b3.config(bg="red")

def b3_pressed():
    b1.config(bg="red")
    b2.config(bg="red")
    b3.config(bg="gray")
```

That's a lot of repetition, so what you can do instead is pass information about the button that has been pressed to the handler.

```
b1 = Button(frame, text = "v", command=lambda: button_pressed(b1))
b2 = Button(frame, text = "v", command=lambda: button_pressed(b2))
b3 = Button(frame, text = "v", command=lambda: button_pressed(b3))

def button_pressed(button):
    for b in [b1, b2, b3]:
        if b is button:
            b.config(bg="gray")
        else:
            b.config(bg="red")
```

We need the `lambda` in there to wrap the call to `button_pressed` so we can pass the value (as you currently do for config in your example). The target function takes this button reference and compares it against each member of a list of possible buttons. If it matches we set that button to gray, if it doesn't we set it to red.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can u please suggest me for the main button function how to check 'if the button is gray.' to define command of the button B.

Comment: @ali to check the background you can use `button.cget('bg')` I believe. The full config of a button is also available by calling `button.config()` with no params, which returns a `dict`

Comment: @mfitzp- I used- if b1.config(bg="gray"): but it didn't work for me. Can u please suggest something

Comment: @mfitzp- Is it possible to make the other buttons transparent when I click one button? If so can you please suggest me.

Comment: @ali `b1.config(bg='gray')` is *setting* the value, you want `if b1.cget('bg') == 'gray'`. To make it transparent I think you can set the background to `''` (empty string) and it will revert to the default.

Comment: @mfitzp- unfortunately, i got an error-tkinter.TclError:unknown color name "" if I set the background to empty string.

Comment: @ali You can get the current default from your `root` or `master` object (that you created with `Tk()` e.g  `root.cget('bg')`  — if you set the button to that it works  e.g. `b1.config(bg=root.cget('bg'))`